# Is there a possibility to return truly blank values from Excel custom function?

Tags: office-js, excel-addins, custom-functions-excel

I am trying to write an Excel custom function that returns a dynamic array containing timestamps and values. In some cases it is possible that a timestamp does not have a value. In this case I would like the value in the dynamic array to be truly blank.
I need this because I want to create a graph using the data from the dynamic array, and as long as i return `''` or `null` for an empty cell, Excel interprets it as 0 and the graph does not look correct (I would like the graph to interpolate the data when there is a blank cell)

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have a concept of "blank" that is distinct from `null` and `'' `. Can you manually create a table that does what you want in Excel? If it can't be done manually, then it can't be done with the Office JavaScript library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For custom function, we can't return blank content or NULL. Dynamic array will return 0 for empty cell and it's by design behavior. You may try an empty string as a workaround but it will definitely change the content in the file.